# Combining User Likes with Content-Based Recommendation System

Tags: algorithm, vector, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have a set of 4-dimensional feature vectors, `V1 { D1, D2, D3, D4 }, ... Vn { D1, ... D4 }` on which, given a query, `Q1 { D1, ... D4 }` I am calculating a distance metric between `Q1` and each of `V1 ... Vn` to determine similarity. I return the 5 nearest neighbors as my recommendations and this is working okay.

I also have vectors of users who have expressed a preference for certain feature vectors. So `U1 { V1, V2 }, U2 { V1, V8 }, U3 { V1, V2, V4, V8 },` etc.

I'm stuck on how to reconcile both systems so that given `Ui { V1, ... Vn }`  and `Vn { D1, ... D4 }` my recommendation engine returns a refined set of neighbors particular to `Ui`.

My first thought is to take each V liked by Ui as a separate query, return those recommendations, and then merge the result sets to find the 5 nearest neighbors. But Ui can have many members, and Vn can be very large so that seems expensive and probably not the optimal solution.

I haven't been able to find any resources on this but perhaps I'm using the wrong terms. I hope I've used the notation correctly and explained this clearly, I'm learning as I go along.

Comment: What distance metric are you using for similarity? The question is too general: Do you have a specific CF algorithm in mind or you are open to any one?

Comment: I'm using Manhattan distance for similarity right now and I'm open to any CF algorithm that could work in this circumstance.

Comment: To be more specific, I think I am looking for pointers, techniques, and best practices in developing a hybrid recommendation system.

Starting with http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0888613X10000460

Comment: Ui { V1 { D1, ... D4 } , ... Vn { Dx, ... Dy } }